# Trouble shooting using Pythonnet and setting Runtime.PythonDLL property

Tags: python, .net, clr, python.net

I try to use an assembly for .NET framework 4.8 via Pythonnet. I am using version 3.0.1 with Python 3.10. The documentation of Pythonnet is stating:

> You must set Runtime.PythonDLL property or PYTHONNET_PYDLL environment variable starting with version 3.0, otherwise you will receive BadPythonDllException (internal, derived from MissingMethodException) upon calling Initialize. Typical values are python38.dll (Windows), libpython3.8.dylib (Mac), libpython3.8.so (most other Unix-like operating systems).

However, the documentation unfortunately is not stating how the property is set and I do not understand how to do this.

When I try:

```
import clr
from pythonnet import load

load('netfx')

clr.AddReference(r'path\to\my.dll')
```

unsurprisingly the following error is coming up

```
Failed to initialize pythonnet: System.InvalidOperationException: This property must be set before runtime is initialized
   bei Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)
   bei Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
   bei Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)
   bei Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
[...]
in load
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll")
RuntimeError: Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll
```

The question now is, where and how the Runtime.PythonDLL property or PYTHONNET_PYDLL environment variable is set

Thanks,
Jens

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your use case is for *Embedding .NET in Python* however, the way I understand the requirement to "set `Runtime.PythonDLL` property" is that is for *Embedding Python in .NET* which was my use case. Anyhow, maybe the following will be useful.

Hidden at the bottom of the main GitHub [README.md](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/README.rst) is a link to [the WiKi](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki) (and of course the tab at the top of the GitHub repo) where thankfully there is a lot more detailed information and links to useful articles.

The main `README.md` asserts `Runtime.PythonDLL` "must be set" yet their example code does not illustrate doing so. Furthermore, [the documentation](https://pythonnet.github.io/pythonnet/dotnet.html) on the official website asserts `Python.Runtime.dll` must be "referenced" which further confuses things.

In my experience `Python.Runtime.dll` was automatically referenced when installing the `pythonnet` NuGet package via Visual Studio. Perhaps `Python.Runtime.dll` does not automatically get referenced in earlier version or maybe when Python.NET is installed in other ways other than by using NuGet?

To answer your question "how to set `Runtime.PythonDLL` property?". My understanding is the way that is done is by assigning a string path to that property before the other usual setup:

```
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python38.dll"
```

In my case, I found this path by using `where python` on Windows (`which` in bash, or `Get-Command` in PowerShell):

```
C:\>where python
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because `import clr` internally calls `pythonnet.load`, and in the version of pythonnet you are using this situation does not print any warning.

E.g. the right way is to call `load` before you call `import clr` for the first time.

Comment: if i do:

from pythonnet import load
load('netfx')
import clr
clr.AddReference(r'path\to\my.dll')

I get the following error:
System.BadImageFormatException

In the meanwhile however I managed to access the dll via ctypes. But would be interesting what I am doing wrong here anyway.

Comment: `BadImageFormatException` usually means your DLL bitness does not match the bitness of your process.